# Child thread can't update parent thread variable?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, aiosmtpd

I found a very perplexing issue in [aiosmtpd/244](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/issues/244), sharing my puzzlement here to help me find inspiration on how to troubleshoot.

### Situation

- Two servers running Red Hat 7.9
- [Works on one](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/issues/244#issuecomment-775836087), doesn't work on the other
- Problematic code, simplified:

```py
>>> from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller
>>> from aiosmtpd.handlers import Sink
>>> cont = Controller(Sink())
>>> cont.start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiosmtpd/controller.py", line 180, in start
    raise RuntimeError("Unknown Error, failed to init SMTP server")
RuntimeError: Unknown Error, failed to init SMTP server
```

The above RuntimeError can only be generated if, [at the end of the `start()` method, `self.smtpd` is still None](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/blob/dd255876a69133c50d1ffd9ad1cae87bffdd8c8d/aiosmtpd/controller.py#L175-L177).

### Expected flow

`start()` -> `_run()` -> `loop.create_server()`

Then upon first connection:

`loop.create_server()` -> `_factory_invoker()` -> `factory()`

The attribute `smtpd` is set within `_factory_invoker` in [these lines](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/blob/dd255876a69133c50d1ffd9ad1cae87bffdd8c8d/aiosmtpd/controller.py#L94-L103):

```py
        try:
            self.smtpd = self.factory()
            if self.smtpd is None:
                raise RuntimeError("factory() returned None")
            return self.smtpd
        except Exception as err:
            self._thread_exception = err
            return _FakeServer(self.loop)
```

`self._thread_exception` is interpreted in [these lines](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/blob/dd255876a69133c50d1ffd9ad1cae87bffdd8c8d/aiosmtpd/controller.py#L173-L177):

```py
        if self._thread_exception is not None:
            raise self._thread_exception
        # Defensive
        if self.smtpd is None:
            raise RuntimeError("Unknown Error, failed to init SMTP server")
```

As you can see, if `self.smtpd` is `None`, then it would only happen if there's an error in `_factory_invoker()`. If so, the error should've been caught and recorded in `self._thread_exception`. If `self._thread_exception` is `None`, then `_factory_invoker()` had succeeded, and thus `self.smtpd` couldn't be `None`.

My main problem in troubleshooting this is that on *all* my test systems (Windows, Ubuntu, OpenSUSE, MacOS, and FreeBSD), I never encountered a similar error.

So I'm stumped. I'd appreciate any ideas on solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so apparently I was sent on a wild goose chase.

The compounding factor is because **I have suppressed *ALL* exceptions** in [these lines](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/blob/dd255876a69133c50d1ffd9ad1cae87bffdd8c8d/aiosmtpd/controller.py#L167-L172):

```py
        try:
            self._testconn()
        except Exception:
            # We totally don't care of exceptions experienced by _testconn,
            # which _will_ happen if factory() experienced problems.
            pass
```

As a result, a *very* helpful exception raised within `self._testconn()` was swallowed.

Apparently `self._testconn()` failed in its attempt to connect to the `host:port`, and thus `_factory_invoker()` ***never*** got called.

Once the `try..except` block is modified to *only* swallow `socket.socket_timeout`, the actual problem reared its head, and we can quickly fix it.

It's all documented in [aiosmtpd/244](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/issues/244) and thus I won't repeat them here :-)

Thank you all who spent the time & effort to try solving this puzzle!